# Query type of video card connections (HDMI/VGA/DVI/ETC)

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, vga, dvi, wmi

I need to find a way to query types of video connections available on a large list of machines.  I wasn't able to find a property within the following WMI classes:

Win32_VideoController
Win32_VideoConfiguration
Win32_VideoSettings 
Win32_DisplayControllerConfiguration
Win32_DisplayConfiguration

Does anyone know of another WMI class/other utility that is capable of providing this information?

Answer (score 1):

Try the WmiMonitorConnectionParams class, it has VideoOutputTechnology property which returns these values:-

```
> typedef enum _D3DKMDT_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY { 
  D3DKMDT_VOT_UNINITIALIZED         = -2,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_OTHER                 = -1,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_HD15                  = 0,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_SVIDEO                = 1,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_COMPOSITE_VIDEO       = 2,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_COMPONENT_VIDEO       = 3,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_DVI                   = 4,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_HDMI                  = 5,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_LVDS                  = 6,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_D_JPN                 = 8,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_SDI                   = 9,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_DISPLAYPORT_EXTERNAL  = 10,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_DISPLAYPORT_EMBEDDED  = 11,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_UDI_EXTERNAL          = 12,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_UDI_EMBEDDED          = 13,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_SDTVDONGLE            = 14,
#if (DXGKDDI_INTERFACE_VERSION >= DXGKDDI_INTERFACE_VERSION_WDDM1_3_M1)
  D3DKMDT_VOT_MIRACAST              = 15,
#endif 
  D3DKMDT_VOT_INTERNAL              = 0x80000000,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_SVIDEO_4PIN           = D3DKMDT_VOT_SVIDEO,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_SVIDEO_7PIN           = D3DKMDT_VOT_SVIDEO,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_RF                    = D3DKMDT_VOT_COMPOSITE_VIDEO,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_RCA_3COMPONENT        = D3DKMDT_VOT_COMPONENT_VIDEO,
  D3DKMDT_VOT_BNC                   = D3DKMDT_VOT_COMPONENT_VIDEO
} D3DKMDT_VIDEO_OUTPUT_TECHNOLOGY;
```